# How to search for matches from an array of pairs for a certain number of rows in a ListBox?

Tags: for-loop, listbox, numericupdown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEMeM.jpg)I want to write a program to analyze the lottery. I want to implement Visual Basic.NET in ListBox. The base of circulations in ListBox will look like this:
1344 - 03 34 12 02 45 21
1345 - 33 10 06 18 19 02
1346 - 39 01 15 27 04 19
I want to make a filter to search for pairs, triplets and units dropped out for a certain number of runs. I thought to implement this through For and then, but I don’t know how to implement such an algorithm. Filtering settings for how many runs I want to search for through NumericUpDown, so that you can change the search conditions. I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Can you please post the code you use to build the object or array? That will help us understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am currently on a business trip. Haven't done sketches yet.